# R data.table's fread() doubles quotes instrings on every read attempt

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I searched for this question, but have not found exactly my case. I work with strings that often contain double quotes for the quotes or names. When I `fread` .csv files with such strings I get doubling of my double quotes, and if I save and read again, I get one more double quotes aroung the quoted part:

> He said ""I liked fread"".

```
library(data.table)

dt <-
     data.table(
          txt = c('Hey', 'He said "I liked fread".')
          )

fwrite(dt, 'dt.csv')

dt2 <- fread('dt.csv', sep = ',')
```

I tried various options inside `fread` but failed. Is it possible to overcome this behaviour using `fread`?

Comment: Maybe I was too quick to close but the following works for me:`fwrite(dt, 'dt.csv', quote = FALSE)` and `fread("dt.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")`

Comment: It is a valuable information. I made an experiment that showed that doubling the double quotes happens after *fwrite*. The string saved on disk looks this way: "He said ""I liked fread""." So, the string was quoted and double quotes doubled. I think my question can be closed. Thank you!!